# Is it 'recite over' or 'recite back'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, sentence, syntactic-analysis

> He was buried behind the newspaper like someone was going to ask him
>   to recite it over.

In the above sentence, would it be better to use the phrase 'recite it back' in place of 'recite it over'?

Comment: It might be better to drop the last word altogether and stop at "recite it". But "recite it over" and "recite it back" are somewhat different. We'll need more context to determine which is more appropriate here. You can post more context via the [edit] link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say " .... like someone was going to ask him to recite its contents." No one can recite a newspaper, only the words written on it. (Admin and OP: this is just my *opinion*. I cannot provide chapter and verse.)